# numerical scheme for SDE and empirical estimation of rate of convergence

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider $\{X_t , t \geq 0 \}$ real valued diffusion satisfying
$$
d X_t = b(X_t) d t + \sigma (X_t) d W_t, \quad X_0 = x \in \mathbb{R} 
$$
where $b, \sigma$ are well-behaved functions and $W$ is a real valued Wiener process.

For the probabilistic numerical scheme, we consider a time step $\delta t \triangleq \frac{T}{N}$ and a sequence of times 
$t_n \triangleq n \delta t$ for $n = 0 .. N_{\delta}$ where $T$ is a fixed time and $N_{\delta t}$ is an integer. We construct inductively $N_{\delta t}$ random variables $\{ X_n, 1 \leq n \leq N_{\delta t} \}$. Here, for each $1 \leq n \leq N_{\delta t}$, $X_n$ is an approximation of $X_{t_n}$.

Then for any well-behaved function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we proceed with the following approximation
$u_M^{\delta t} \approx u$ where
$$
u_M^{\delta t} \triangleq \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M f(X_{N_{\delta t}}^m)
\quad 
\mbox{and}
\quad
u \triangleq \mathbb{E} f(X_T). 
$$ 
and 
$\{ X^m, m = 1 ... M \}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of trajectories produced by the numerical scheme.

Define $\mathcal{E}_M^{\delta t} \triangleq |u_M^{\delta t} - u|$.

**question:** How to empirically (and smartly) estimate the rate of convergence of $\mathcal{E}_M^{\delta t}$ to $0$ with respect $\delta t$ and $M$ knowing that we can only compute $u_M^{\delta t}$ for a bunch of values of $\delta t$ and $M$? It includes the Monte Carlo and the the corresponding numerical scheme errors.

I hope it is a fine question.